# Match all keywords on a row using encrypted blob fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, encryption, blob

I have a MySQL table where text fields are stored as BLOB, using AES_ENCRYPT. I need to match several keywords against the rows, with the condition that ALL keywords must exist in a row for it to be returned. While this works great using MATCH/AGAINST on non-encrypted fields, no luck with my set-up.

My "people" table:

```
+============+===========+
| name_first | name_last |
+============+===========+
| John       | Smith     |
+------------+-----------+
| Jane       | Smith     |
+============+===========+
```

For example, when searching for "John" and "Smith", only rows that actually contain both these keywords should be returned. Rows with first name "Jane" and last name "Smith" shouldn't be matched.

The only select that seems to be working is when using LIKE:

```
SELECT 
AES_DECRYPT(name_first,"MyKey"),
AES_DECRYPT(name_last,"MyKey") 
FROM people 
WHERE (LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_first,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%john%" 
OR LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_last,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%john%" 
OR LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_first,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%smith%" 
OR LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_last,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%smith%")
```

However, my SELECT returns both the John and Jane records.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some time and research I found that the only solution to my problem was creating a temporary MySQL (only exists during the execution of the PHP script), feed it with non-encrypted data from my encrypted table and then do a MATCH/AGAINST. The search is terrible slow since the table is quite big, but what can you do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT 
  AES_DECRYPT(name_first,"MyKey"),
  AES_DECRYPT(name_last,"MyKey") 
FROM people 
  WHERE (LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_first,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%john%" 
     AND LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_last,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%smith%")
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried using AND in the search, which is no good. The problem is that the keyword input can be one or several words and there is no way to know which keyword should be matched against the first name or last name. Someone could be searching for "smith" and then "john", rendering the WHERE statement: LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_first,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%smith %" AND LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(name_last,"MyKey") USING latin1)) LIKE "%john%")

Comment: This will be tough (encryption notwithstanding) if you can't limit the search values by column.